# WP List table not showing data [Wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a plugin to show all the users with their email and role using WP List Table however the information is not being displayed, it counts how many users I have in the DB but nothing shows, please advise:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class Users_List extends WP_List_Table {

    /** Class constructor */
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct( [
            'singular' => __( 'User', 'sp' ), //singular name of the listed records
            'plural'   => __( 'Users', 'sp' ), //plural name of the listed records
            'ajax'     => false //does this table support ajax?
        ] );

    }


    /**
     * Retrieve users data from the database
     *
     * @param int $per_page
     * @param int $page_number
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function get_users( $per_page = 5, $page_number = 1 ) {

        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users";

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) ) {
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['orderby'] );
            $sql .= ! empty( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ? ' ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : ' ASC';
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT $per_page";
        $sql .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;


        $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * Delete a user record.
     *
     * @param int $id user ID
     */
    public static function delete_users( $id ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $wpdb->delete(
            "{$wpdb->prefix}users",
            [ 'ID' => $id ],
            [ '%d' ]
        );
    }


    /**
     * Returns the count of records in the database.
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public static function record_count() {
        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users";

        return $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
    }


    /** Text displayed when no user data is available */
    public function no_items() {
        _e( 'No users avaliable.', 'sp' );
    }


    public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch ( $column_name ) {
            case 'email':
            case 'role':
                return $item[ $column_name ];
            default:
                return print_r( $item, true ); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
        }
    }

    /**
     * Render the bulk edit checkbox
     *
     * @param array $item
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function column_cb( $item ) {
        return sprintf(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="bulk-delete[]" value="%s" />', $item['ID']
        );
    }


    /**
     * Method for name column
     *
     * @param array $item an array of DB data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function column_name( $item ) {

        $delete_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'sp_delete_users' );

        $title = '<strong>' . $item['name'] . '</strong>';

        $actions = [
            'delete' => sprintf( '<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&users=%s&_wpnonce=%s">Delete</a>', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['page'] ), 'delete', absint( $item['ID'] ), $delete_nonce )
        ];

        return $title . $this->row_actions( $actions );
    }


    /**
     *  Associative array of columns
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function get_columns() {
        $columns = [
            'cb'      => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'name'    => __( 'Name', 'sp' ),
            'email' => __( 'Email', 'sp' ),
            'role'    => __( 'Role', 'sp' )
        ];

        return $columns;
    }


    /**
     * Columns to make sortable.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_sortable_columns() {
        $sortable_columns = array(
            'name' => array( 'name', true ),
            'email' => array( 'email', false )
        );

        return $sortable_columns;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an associative array containing the bulk action
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_bulk_actions() {
        $actions = [
            'bulk-delete' => 'Delete'
        ];

        return $actions;
    }


    /**
     * Handles data query and filter, sorting, and pagination.
     */
    public function prepare_items() {

        $this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();

        /** Process bulk action */
        $this->process_bulk_action();

        $per_page     = $this->get_items_per_page( 'users_per_page', 5 );
        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
        $total_items  = self::record_count();

        $this->set_pagination_args( [
            'total_items' => $total_items, //WE have to calculate the total number of items
            'per_page'    => $per_page //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
        ] );

        $this->items = self::get_users( $per_page, $current_page );
    }

    public function process_bulk_action() {

        //Detect when a bulk action is being triggered...
        if ( 'delete' === $this->current_action() ) {

            // In our file that handles the request, verify the nonce.
            $nonce = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] );

            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'sp_delete_users' ) ) {
                die( 'Go get a life script kiddies' );
            }
            else {
                self::delete_users( absint( $_GET['user'] ) );

                        // esc_url_raw() is used to prevent converting ampersand in url to "#038;"
                        // add_query_arg() return the current url
                        wp_redirect( esc_url_raw(add_query_arg()) );
                exit;
            }

        }

        // If the delete bulk action is triggered
        if ( ( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'bulk-delete' )
             || ( isset( $_POST['action2'] ) && $_POST['action2'] == 'bulk-delete' )
        ) {

            $delete_ids = esc_sql( $_POST['bulk-delete'] );

            // loop over the array of record IDs and delete them
            foreach ( $delete_ids as $id ) {
                self::delete_users( $id );

            }

            // esc_url_raw() is used to prevent converting ampersand in url to "#038;"
                // add_query_arg() return the current url
                wp_redirect( esc_url_raw(add_query_arg()) );
            exit;
        }
    }

}


class SP_Plugin {

    // class instance
    static $instance;

    // user WP_List_Table object
    public $users_obj;

    // class constructor
    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'set-screen-option', [ __CLASS__, 'set_screen' ], 10, 3 );
        add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'plugin_menu' ] );
    }


    public static function set_screen( $status, $option, $value ) {
        return $value;
    }

    public function plugin_menu() {

        $hook = add_menu_page(
            'Elvio User Plugin',
            'SP WP_List_Table',
            'manage_options',
            'wp_list_table_class',
            [ $this, 'plugin_settings_page' ]
        );

        add_action( "load-$hook", [ $this, 'screen_option' ] );

    }


    /**
     * Plugin settings page
     */
    public function plugin_settings_page() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Elvio User Plugin</h2>

            <div id="poststuff">
                <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-2">
                    <div id="post-body-content">
                        <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
                            <form method="post">
                                <?php
                                $this->users_obj->prepare_items();
                                $this->users_obj->display(); ?>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }

    /**
     * Screen options
     */
    public function screen_option() {

        $option = 'per_page';
        $args   = [
            'label'   => 'users',
            'default' => 5,
            'option'  => 'users_per_page'
        ];

        add_screen_option( $option, $args );

        $this->users_obj = new Users_List();
    }


    /** Singleton instance */
    public static function get_instance() {
        if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

}


add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function () {
    SP_Plugin::get_instance();
} );
```

I´m not experienced in PHP, however, I have checked everything and the issue persists

Comment: The [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) for `WP_List_Table` says: "This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not intended for use by plugin and theme developers...". So why would anyone want to start debugging your code now?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you - I think it's wrong to use a piece of code that was marked as "Do not use" and then ask others to figure it out. Just my opinion.

Comment: I use the same code, I think the problem is the database, not import property. Please check your DB.

Comment: @Hans, even though it is a private class, developers extend `WP_List_Table` because there is no other choice for creating a custom list page similar to the other Wordpress admin screens.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this problem today and by chance I was following what I assume was the [same tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp-list-table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/) you read --or at least it presents very similar code--.

In my case, the table didn't show the data because the tutorial missed something important. I want to direct your attention to the `Users_List::prepare_items` method. The problem is at this line

```php
$this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();
```

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/#extended-properties), `WP_List_Table::_column_headers` is a matrix containing 3 arrays:

1. An array with **all the columns** in the table
2. Another array with the **hidden columns** --that is, columns that should not be rendered.
3. The last one with the **sortable columns**.

Hence, the previous line of code should have been written in this way:

```php
$this->_column_headers = [
  $this->get_column_info(), // all the columns
  [], // hidden columns
  [] // sortable columns
];
```

That was enough to make my code work.